# Fill Barcode PDF-417 in PDF using ITEXT for a field identifier

Tags: itext, barcode, pdf417

I need to generate a PDF417 barcode and fill it in a PDF field for which I have the filed identifier using ITEXT API.

I have used several ways such as

Way 1

```
      PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
      BarcodePDF417 pf = new BarcodePDF417();
      pf.setText("Some text value for encoding");
      Rectangle size = pf.getBarcodeSize();

      PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
      pf.placeBarcode(template, BaseColor.BLACK, 5, 5);
      Image image = Image.getInstance(template);
      image.setAbsolutePosition(35f, 40f);
      cb.addImage(image);
```

The issue here is the barcode is not of right size and is not placed at correct position.

Way 2.

```
  BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
  barcode.setText("Some text value for encoding");
  barcode.placeBarcode(cb, BaseColor.BLACK, 5, 5);
```

Here too the issue is same, the barcode is not of right size and is not placed at correct position.

I know the field IDENTIFIER for the filed where I need to place the barcode specifically.
Is there a way with which I can get the cell and generate the barcode image of exact size of this cell and place it in?

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally implement this. My code is

```
        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getUnderContent(i);// i being the pdf page number.
        BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
        barcode.setErrorLevel(5);
        barcode.setCodeColumns(30);
        barcode.setCodeRows(5);
        barcode.setOptions(BarcodePDF417.PDF417_FIXED_RECTANGLE);
        barcode.setText(<Byte[] - aka byte array of the text that needs to be encoded.>);
        Rectangle rect = barcode.getBarcodeSize();

        PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(2 + rect.getWidth(), 2 + rect.getHeight());

        barcode.placeBarcode(template, BaseColor.BLACK, 1, 1);

        Image image = Image.getInstance(template);
        image.scaleAbsolute(535, 135);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(40f, 40f);
        cb.addImage(image);
```